# rotate() transform not working with particular parameters?

Tags: css, trigonometry, css-transforms

I have a box in the top left corner of a document.  I want to rotate it using a transform so that one of its edges is pointing toward the lower right corner of the viewport.  Based on my reading of the relevant specs, this seems like it ought to work.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#oriented {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  outline: solid black 2px;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(atan2(100vh, 100vw));
}
```

```html
<div id="oriented"></div>
```

However, it doesn't work as expected.  Firefox doesn't rotate the box at all.  Chrom-ish browsers put it at a fixed 45° angle, regardless of viewport.  Is there any way to get this working?  Is this a bug in the browsers, or am I misunderstanding the specs?

Comment: I tried experimenting e.g. with 100vh, 100px and same problem (though https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/atan2 claims mixing in this way should also work)

Comment: The `atan2` part seems to be innocent; I tried setting `background: linear-gradient(atan2(100vh, 100vw), black, white)` and that behaves as expected.

Comment: Doesn't seem to actually use the viewport dimensions though.  Try resizing the window.  Nothing changes on my end.

Comment: From the [CSS specifications](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#trig-funcs), "All of [the arc trigonometric functions] contain a single [calculation](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#calc-calculation) which must resolve to a [<number>](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#number-value)". Here, your parameters would resolve to a `<length>` since you are using a mixture of units. It seems (at least testing in Chrome) that browsers discard the units, as can be seen with `rotate(atan2(50vh, 100vw))` vs `rotate(atan2(50, 100))`.

Comment: What is the reason you use these values `atan2(100vh, 100vw)`?..

Comment: @Wongjn read the next paragraph dealing specifically with atan2

Answer (score 1):

Dividing two lengths to get a number is something defined in the Spec but has no support yet so your code may work in the future but not now.

You can try `calc(50vw/100vw)` which actually invalid but in the future it should give you `0.5`

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: calc(50vw/100vw); /* inspect the code to see it's invalid */
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Same logic with your code since `atan2(100vh, 100vw)` is equivalent to `atan(100vh/100vw)`.

it seems that chrome is doing the effort to convert your code into something valid but it's clearly not the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Although it initially calculates any value with a unit (ex. px, em, vh, vw, etc.), the CSS function `atan2()` doesn't recalculate dynamically according to relative unit lengths changing (ex. like when the width of the viewport changes `vw` changes).

I don't know exactly what you're objective is so I made an interactive example so you can adjust `x` and `y` on the fly. The point of this demo is to show what `atan2()` is capable of doing given various values. If you use the developer tools you'll notice that `section.square` has a `style` attribute which is the equivalent of having `transform: rotate(calc(`**NUMBER**`deg))` in CSS (**NUMBER** is the result of `atan2()`). See **Figure I**.

### Figure I

[image]

## Example

**Note:** Review in *Full Page* mode, the demo viewed through this iframe is an inaccurate representation.

```js
// Allows form#ui to react to user input
document.forms.ui.oninput = rotate;

// Runs whenever the user inputs data in form#ui
function rotate(e) {
  // References all <input> and <output>
  const fc = this.elements;
  // Collect all data
  let x = fc.x.value;
  let y = fc.y.value;
  // Reference output#angle
  let deg = fc.angle;
  // Reference section.square
  const sq = document.querySelector(".square");
  /**
   * The CSS property 'transform: rotate()' is assigned
   * directly to section.square. The value is calculated by  
   * the atan2() CSS function. 
   */
  sq.style.cssText = `transform: rotate(atan2(${x}, ${y}));`
  const cs = getComputedStyle(sq);
  let matrix = cs.getPropertyValue("transform");
  /**
   * The proceeding code can be found at:
   * https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/
   */
  let values = matrix.split('(')[1];
  values = values.split(')')[0];
  values = values.split(',');
  let a = values[0];
  let b = values[1];
  let c = values[2];
  let d = values[3];
  let scale = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
  let sin = b / scale;
  let angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180 / Math.PI));
  // Display the rotation angle of section.square
  deg.value = angle+'°';
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 5vmin/1 Consolas;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.viewport-guide {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  outline: 3px dashed red;
  outline-offset: -10px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.square {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  outline: 2px solid black;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(atan2(41, 100));
  overflow: visible;
}

#ui {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 15px;
}

label {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40vw;
}

label:first-of-type {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

label:last-of-type {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

input {
  width: 10vw;
  font: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px inset lightgrey;
}

label:hover input {
  background: yellow;
}

label:hover::after {
  content: 'REQUIRED: Enter a number (Negative and floats are allowed)';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 20vw;
  top: -20vh;
  width: 50vw;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  color: blue;
  white-space: break-spaces;
  background: gold;
  box-shadow: rgba(6, 24, 44, 0.4) 0px 0px 0px 2px, rgba(6, 24, 44, 0.65) 0px 4px 6px -1px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08) 0px 1px 0px inset;
  cursor: help;
}

#angle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 1px;
  width: 125vw;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}
```

```html
<main class="viewport-guide">
  <section class="square">
    <output id="angle" form="ui"></output>
  </section>
  <form id="ui">
    <label>X:&nbsp;
      <input id="x" type="number" value="41">
    </label>
    <label>Y:&nbsp;
      <input id="y" type="number" value="100">
    </label>
  </form>
</main>
```

Comment: I might be missing something; [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/atan2) `y` (vertical) comes before `x` (horizontal), so `atan2(100vh, 100vw)` is correct, is it not?

Comment: I'm trying to do it in css not js. I think the parameter order is correct.  I used top left so that the corner of the block stays anchored to the corner of the document.

Comment: Thanks, please see update.  The JavaScript is not the answer, it shows what `atan2()` does with numbers applied just as it would be if in a stylesheet.